# How do I dump one project out of an SVN repository which contains multiple projects?

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndump, svndumpfilter

I am working with an SVN repository with many projects. I need to move a few of the projects out of that repository into individual repositories, one for each project, keeping the history.

I've been able to use `svnadmin dump` to dump the entire repository and `svnadmin load` it into another repository, but I can't find a way of dumping only one project from the original repository so I can load it into the new one. Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: I like to share one pitfall that i ran into: filtering for a subfolder, also filters out the creation of the parent folder. So one has to create the parent folder in the target repository manually.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use the [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svndumpfilter) utility to do this. The SVN book has a [good explanation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering) of how to do this.

For instance, one way would be:

```
$ svnadmin dump /path/to/repo 
     | svndumpfilter include /proj > dump-file
$ svnadmin create /new/proj/repo
$ svnadmin load --ignore-uuid /new/proj/repo < dump-file
$ svn rm file:///path/to/repo/proj
```

Comment: Thanks Avi, I've just read the docs and it look like that's what I needed.

Comment: you forgot to input the dumpfile to the svnadmin load command.

Comment: Thanks, Wimmel. I didn't actually forget; I forgot to escape the less-than sign. Fixed now.

Comment: it might be worth noting that the args --drop-empty-revs and --renumber-revs can be used with svndumpfilter to clean up gaps in the revision numbers

Comment: Can any user perform these actions or do they require admin privileges?

Comment: @ziggy any user can do this if they have access to the svnadmin command and the raw repo files (ie access to the server its running on).

Comment: What if I want to dump multiple projects..?

Answer (score 0):

Just an small addition to @Avi answer and @Kit comment.

If you use `svndumpfilter`, you may lose a commit that is necessary for loading the repository ([source](http://www.celticwolf.com/blog/2010/05/03/subversion-svnadmin-load-error-file-not-found-transaction-0-1-path/comment-page-1/)).

In my case:

```
cat dump | svndumpfilter --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs include trunk/project > project.dump 
svnadmin load --ignore-uuid /opt/svn/newlocation < project.dump
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1 
svnadmin: File not found: transaction '0-0', path 'trunk/project'
```

The solution was to commit an upper directory `trunk` first.

Comment: This solution renumbers the revisions. When you don't want to renumber the revisions just don't use --drop-empty-revs and --renumber-revs.