# Moving only certain change lists to new SVN server

Tags: svn, svndump, svndumpfilter

I want to move to a new SVN server.

On my current server I have a load of really old stuff in there that I don't really care about - I want to move it to the new server but not move any of the history. I have a load of images and stuff in there that will make my nightly backup a lot bigger than it needs to be.
For this code I assume I'll just export it from the old server, delete the images and so on that shouldn't be in there then check into the new server.

I do have some code in there that I do want to retain the full history for.

How do I go about doing a dump for only some of the projects in the repository?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337024/how-do-i-dump-one-project-out-of-a-svn-repository-which-contains-multiple-project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**svndumpfilter**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch05s03.html) is the general-purpose answer to that question. I've never used it myself yet so I can't give you any syntax examples, but the book chapter may get you at least started.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like exactly what I'm after

Answer (score 0):

I've just gone through this and ran into a number of dramas. The whole process is covered here and might save you some grief: http://www.troyhunt.com/2009/12/black-art-of-splitting-subversion.html