# Perforce to Subversion migration

Tags: perl, svn, migration, perforce

I am going to use [p42svn](http://p42svn.tigris.org) for the first time and I have some doubts/questions regarding the same.

1. As I understand from the [p42svn](http://p42svn.tigris.org) home page, the script p42svn.pl should be run from the machine that hosts the Perforce repository. This script generates an SVN readable dump file which can then be imported into SVN repository. Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct?
2. In our scenario, we do not want to have all the revisions of the files. We would only need the revisions for the past 1 year. Is it possible to achieve the same?
3. Instead of migrating all the projects from the Perforce Depot in one go, is it possible to migrate the Projects one by one?

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the script myself, but reading the [documentation](http://p42svn.tigris.org/source/browse/*checkout*/p42svn/tags/0.21/www/p42svn.html) leads me to:

1. yes.
2. Use the `--changes` switch. Find the relevant changes
   with `p4 changes -s submitted @2010/11/17,@now` (that would give
   you the changes starting a year ago, adjust to your needs)
3. My SVN knowledge is not good enough for this to comment on, but maybe the
   answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337024/how-do-i-dump-one-project-out-of-a-svn-repository-which-contains-multiple-projec) helps?